# Problems with long duration of system self in Chrome performance analysis

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, profiling

Currently I am building a website in Angular that has several canvas areas. However, a "mousemove"-Event results in poorer performance in the Chrome performance test ([part of the perfomance test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPldU.png)). The proportion of "system self" is very high in contrast to the other areas ([propotion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEIua.png)). Does anyone know how to reduce this part or why the proportion can be so big?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would have a look at the green block at the end of the task below the gray block. Maybe you were calling a compute intensive functions on your canvas. Some functions, which can produce perfomance issues are blur(), clip() or save()/restore(), if you are calling them often.
I hope that helps you a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was the ctx.clip(). :)

Comment: thanks for this comment. in my case I was just doing a ton of bezier curves, and while it's hard to tell since it's just a grey block that says "System (self)" I believe it is probably working on canvas stuff